# Magento block user email extension

Tags: magento

Hi how can i block an user email extension for being registered? For example i don't want users register using this email extension `@example.com`. Is there a default way in magento to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can add one new class with regex to validate example.com domain enter by customer.

Just add it to your validation.js like this

```
/@example.com\s*$/.test(mystring)
is true if the string ends in @example.com (plus optional whitespace).
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: dont have any plugins for this?

Comment: @zlipper, But above would be better for only few lines code to add in your js rather than to add extra plugin

Comment: where is validation.js located?

Comment: yourproject\js\prototype\validation.js and your class like    ['validate-ssn', 'Please enter a valid social security number. For example 123-45-6789.', function(v) {
            return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$/.test(v);
            }],
    ['validate-zip', 'Please enter a valid zip code. For example 90602 or 90602-1234.', function(v) {
            return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(v);
            }],